# Adding to html elements from jade script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pug

I am new to jade and trying to make a website were context is changing regarding to some data on the server. Since I need to add an unknown amount of div i figured it should look somewhat like this:

```
html
  head
    title Match Support
  body
    script(type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js')

    h1 Some same
    h3 Games:


    #container

    script.
        //var matches = JSON.parse(!{match});
        var matches = !{matchList};

        for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){
            // how to add to #container from here? 
        }
```

I have tried with JQuery but couldn't make it work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you need to read over the Jquery documentation on DOM manipulation...  http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Comment: Though. You should be using a loop in Jade. It's not clear why you have the script block

Comment: So I don't understand why this does not work. Nothing happen:
$("#container").html('<h1>' + matches[i].hometeam + '</h1>');

Comment: Perhaps the length of matches is zero? The loop isn't ran? Hard to tell without a [mcve] of your whole setup

Comment: You are one hell of a genius! Pretty impressive that you can help me out without knowing anything about the rest of my code

Comment: It isn't hard to trace the execution path logic of what you are trying to do, though ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you get the data asynchronously from server, it is not a question to jade, but just a jquery to add elements to DOM, example

```
    matchList.forEach(function(match) {
        var a = "<a class='ui label'>" + match.property + "</a>";
        $('#container').append(a);
    }
```

If you render your *.jade page passing some data there then you can just use for-loop in jade

```
.ui.segment#container
each match in matchList
  a.ui.label
    | #{match.property}
```